# Update all null values in column .netcore console app

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, console-application

I've got a console app which updates a column in the database called InstagramId based off user input. I want to be able to query the database and if there's a instagramId which is null, to update it with the correct instagramID based off their instagramUsername.

I wasn't sure on the approach if I should create a fake table based off all the null instagramIds and then use those to update my column or if theres another cleaner approach. This console app is only a one time use so just a quick fix up.

```
  class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // receive a profile name
            var tasks = new List<Task<InstagramUser>>();
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) continue;
                var profileName = arg;
                var url = $"https://instagram.com/{profileName}";
                tasks.Add(ScrapeInstagram(url));
            }

            try
            {
                var instagramUsers = await Task.WhenAll<InstagramUser>(tasks);
                foreach (var iu in instagramUsers)
                {
                    iu.Display();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }

        }


        public static async Task<InstagramUser> ScrapeInstagram(string url)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // create html document
                    var htmlBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlBody);

                    // select script tags
                    var scripts = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/script");

                    // preprocess result
                    var uselessString = "window._sharedData = ";
                    var scriptInnerText = scripts[0].InnerText
                        .Substring(uselessString.Length)
                        .Replace(";", "");

                    // serialize objects and fetch the user data
                    dynamic jsonStuff = JObject.Parse(scriptInnerText);
                    dynamic userProfile = jsonStuff["entry_data"]["ProfilePage"][0]["graphql"]["user"];

                    //Update database query 
                    string connectionString = @"Server=mockup-dev-db";


                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update ApplicationUser Set InstagramId = '" + userProfile.id + "'" + "where Instagram =  '" + userProfile.username + "'", con);
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }

                    // create an InstagramUser
                    var instagramUser = new InstagramUser
                    {
                        FullName = userProfile.full_name,
                        FollowerCount = userProfile.edge_followed_by.count,
                        FollowingCount = userProfile.edge_follow.count,
                        Id = userProfile.id,
                        url = url
                    };
                    return instagramUser;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Something wrong happened {response.StatusCode} - {response.ReasonPhrase} - {response.RequestMessage}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? A brief look suggests it should work fine.

Comment: it currently works only if for one search at a time. E.g. I would run the debug file and have the username (test.nora) and it would update that users InstagramID. I don't have a query where I'm searching through the database and then updating all the null InstagramID values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are two problems here

1. Retrieving a list of username from the DB which have null instagram IDs
2. For each of these, downloading and populating the instagram ID

It looks like you've already solved 1, so let's look at number 2:

This data can be fetched using an SQL query:

`SELECT Instagram FROM ApplicationUser WHERE InstagramId IS NULL`

In C# this could look like:

```cs
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Instagram FROM ApplicationUser WHERE InstagramId IS NULL", con);
cmd.Connection.Open();
    var instagramUsernames = new List<string>();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        instagramUsernames.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

Now you have all the usernames in the `instagramUsernames` list and can execute your existing code (with minor modifications) in a foreach loop.

Instead of looping through the args you'd now loop through the list of instagramUsernames (so the above code would come at the start of the Main method):
`foreach (var arg in args)`
Would become `foreach (var arg in instagramUsernames)`

Comment: What would I change this to?  // receive a profile name
            var tasks = new List<Task<InstagramUser>>();
            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg)) continue;
                var profileName = arg;
                var url = $"https://instagram.com/{profileName}";
                ta

Comment: Because currently when I run the console app I have to enter a username

Comment: Please see my edit. Also you would need to do a refactor and tidy up.

Comment: That would stay the same: at the moment you loop through the `args`, getting an individual `arg` which becomes the `profileName`. Now instead of looping through `args` you loop through `instagramUsernames` returned from the DB.

Comment: I'm getting a type error on this line - instagramUsernames.Add(reader[0]); not letting me convert an obj to a string. I've tried to apply casting as well but no luck

Comment: Ah that was my mistake, you need to call `GetString`. I've updated the line of code in the answer.

Comment: yup I'be done this instead instagramUsernames.Add(reader.GetString(0));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222499/discussion-between-rprogramr-and-ekke).